# Why keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array when I extract components with keys in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner in React. When I read the doc, [Extracting Components with Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys), I feel confused.

Because there is a sentence, "Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array."

I want to know why keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array when I extract components with keys  in React?

Something I don't know or it's just a regulation?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Keys are used so React knows which element to update and rerender.

Comment: I think you'll find this page useful (it's in the upcoming rewrite of the React docs which are currently in beta): [Why does React need keys?](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys)

Comment: @catgirlkelly I know that, and I want to know why keys don't make sense out of the context of the surrounding array. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @jsejcksn Okay, I'll try to find the answer in the doc. Thanks for your answer and the docs.

Comment: Adding keys to components that are not directly rendered under an array doesn't do anything. React only tracks keys of components that are rendered directly (mapping an array to a list of elements).

Comment: @catgirlkelly Thanks for your answer. I think I understand it.

Comment: @catgirlkelly In the case named "Incorrect Key Usage" in the doc I have mentioned in my question. `NumberList` won't track the keys in the `<li>` in the `ListItem`, am I right?